# Methods of maintaining sample data in a database

Tags: sql, database, sample

Firstly, let me apologize for the title, as it probably isn't as clear as I think it is.

What I'm looking for is a way to keep sample data in a database (SQL, 2005 2008 and Express) that get modified every so often. At present I have a handful of scripts to populate the database with a specific set of data, but every time the database is changed all the scripts have to be more or less rewritten and I was looking for some alternatives.

I've seen a number of tools and other software for creating sample data in a database, some free and some not. Are there any other methods I haven’t considered?

Thanks in advance for any input.

Edit: Also, if anyone has any advice at all in dealing with keeping data in sync with a changing application or database, that would be of some help as well.

Comment: Define "sample" for your circumstance.  Do you have a larger pool of data you want a random subset of?  Do you want randomly generated data in a specific format?

Comment: Specific data. There's a list of employee names, IDs and a bunch of associated information that doesn't really change, but the tables in the database do every release.

Comment: So what sample are you looking to have?  Certain records from specific tables?  What's the purpose?

Comment: When the software is tested at present, the test group can run a script to populate the database with data specific to the tests they're running. The protocols they use rely on there being a very specific set of records in the database.

Comment: Why are your tables changing in every release?

Comment: Dunno why exaclty, I'm not on the development team. They say they find that they need to store infomation differnetly or add more items.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for tools for SQL server, go visit [Red Gate Software](http://www.red-gate.com/), they have the best tools. They have a data compare tool that you can use to keep lookup type tables up-to-date and a SQL compare tool that you can use to keep the tables synched up between two datbases. So using SQL data compare, create a datbase with all the sample data you want. Then periodically refresh your testing db (or your prod db if these are strictly lookup type tables) using the compare tool.

I also like the alternative of having a script (you can use Red Gate's tool to create scripts) because that means you can store this info in your source control and use it as part of a deployment package to other servers.

Comment: It looks as though the data compare tool can only compare data in databases with matching tables and columns, or have I misread that? Is it able to reconcile tables and columns that have been renamed, moved, deleted or added?

Comment: I don't know of anything that will know where you might have mapped data to in a change of structure. But those kinds of changes of structure should be rare. If you are doing that, I think writing the migration scripts yourself is by far the best choice. You can also maigrate ussing SSIS, but I find it faster to write scripts most of the time Unless it is a terribly large, complicated data migration.

Comment: The Object Mapping pane in SQL Data Compare can be used to map tables and columns with different names.

Answer (score 0):

You could save them in another database or the same db in different tables distinguished by the name, like employee_test

Answer (score 0):

Joseph,

Do you need to keep just the data in sync, or the schema as well?

One solution to the data question would be SQL Server snapshots. You create a snapshot of your initial configuration, so any changes to the "real" database don't show up in the snapshot. Then, when you need to reset the table, select from the snapshot into a new table. I'm not sure how it will work if the schema changes, but it might be worth a try.

For generation of sample data, the Database project in Visual Studio has functionality that will create fake/random data.

Let me know if this make sense.

Erick

Comment: Makes sense, I'll look into the Snapshots.